# Playframework: a value is not a member of models

Tags: java, javascript, playframework-2.0

I am trying to access loadDiameterData() method of DataLoader class from my template view pipeIndex.scala.html.

I get the following error when I add the nextline to javascript section of template:

```
@diameterLengthArray = @dloader.loadDiameterData();
```

Error:
value loadDiameterData is not a member of models.DataLoader

I include DataLoader to template in following way to the template:

```
@(dloader: models.DataLoader, diameterLengthArray: List[Double])
```

And parts of DataLoader class

```
package models;
...
public class DataLoader {
    public static List<Double> loadDiameterData() {
    List<Double> diameterLengthArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
    diameterLengthArray.add(Component.getPipeLenghtsAccordingToDiameter(0, 101));
    return diameterLengthArray;
}
```

Do you know, why I get that error? I am stuck with this error

Cheers,
Alp

Comment: What happens when you call your function with the class name : `@DataLoader.loadDiameterData()` ?

Comment: Can you paste your "pipeIndex.scala.html" code too?.so that it will help more